# YUP validation of array of object where at least one value is true

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I started using `Yup` with `react-hook-form`, but I have some problems.

Actually I have a watcher that sets at the start an array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "code": "english",
        "value": 0
    },
    {
        "code": "french",
        "value": 0
    },
    {
        "code": "german",
        "value": 0
    },
    {
        "code": "italian",
        "value": 0
    }
]
```

I need to validate that at least 1 value must be true or 1.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone else will need, I did this (for sure there will be a better way), but this working in my case...

```
Yup.array()
        .of(
          Yup.object().shape({
            value: Yup.boolean(),
          }),
        )
        .test({
          name: 'one-true',
          message: 'Required',
          test: (val) => !every(val, ['value', false]),
        }),
```